# Rails: Calling entries from a database with a different controller

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am fairly new with ruby on rails, so I am trying out to create a simple website.

I basically have an sqlite database with 3 tables - users, items and categories. I created the user authentication system

I am trying to make the website so that users can login and add items that belong to a category, then be taken to an index for the user's account where they can review the items their specific user has added.

I have connected items with categories with has_many and belongs_to, but I can't figure out how to associate items with the user that created it.

Afterwards, I can't figure out how to list only the items created by the user which is currently logged in.

In a nutshell, I don't know how to call item from database table 1(controller 1) in the index of database table 2

Comment: Just a question, why have 3 databases? You can have as many tables as you want in ONE database.

Comment: oh, I am sorry, I am new to this, I guess I would have 1 database with 3 tables.

Comment: yup. database is collection of many tables which are inter-related. table is a collection of records which are all the same. sometime people say "user database", they really mean "the user table in a database with many other tables"

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I meant. I am completely new to this, so I am still thinking like a layman

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do the same kind of relationship between item and user as you did with item and category.

```
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :user
```

and your item table needs to have both a category_id and a user_id column.

Then obviously, your User model also needs to declare `has_many :items` just like your Category model already does.

Then in your ItemsController index action, simply set `@items = current_user.items`. Obviously, replace `current_user` with whatever method you have setup to know who the currently logged in user is.

Comment: Alright, and would you mind also telling me how I should edit my _form.html.erb, so that when I go to add new data to the table, it automatically sets the user_id to the current user

Comment: I wouldn't do it in the form, as that would allow someone to maliciously craft a form to add items to the database with someone else's id in that field.  Instead, do it in your create action at the controller level, such as `@item = current_user.items.new(params[:item])` and then `if @item.save ... etc, etc, etc.`